# Python time data '2008-01-24T00:00:00:000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M :%S:%f'

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I'm trying to take this dictionary, and convert the value of the key 'tow_date' to datetime and then print the month.  I've been trying to browse similar questions to no avail. Help? But, I keep getting the error below. I'd really appreciate the help. Thank you.

**Code:**

```
d=[{'unique_key':'200801247RON', 'tow_date':'2008-01-24T00:00:00:000'}]
x=d[0]['tow_date']

y = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")

print(y.month())
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                   
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>                                               
    y = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")                        
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime            
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime                     
    (data_string, format))                                                           
ValueError: time data '2008-01-24T00:00:00:000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
:%S:%f'
```

Comment: `y = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f")`. Also it should be `y.month`, not `y.month()`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `T`, do the following:

```
  y = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f")
  y.month
```

Comment: Thank you very much (and for not being condescending like some people here tend to be)! That worked, and really helped out a lot! I don't know why the sources I looked at didn't include it :/ .